# Determine whether a string contains valid javascript code

Tags: c#, javascript, validation, syntax

I'm looking for a `C#` function which returns `true` if a string contains valid javascript syntax.

For instance:

```
IsValidJavascript("alert('hello');");
```

would return `true`, but

```
IsValidJavascript("alertXXhelloZ);");
```

would return `false`.

Comment: Well run it through interpreter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use an **[interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29)**.
You can try **[Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/)** which is a Javascript interpreter for `.NET`.

Comment: nice solution which does not seem to force the client to actually "execute" the js code to validate, +1

Comment: I too need something similar but mine is a java function, any port/alternate of above mentioned solution in java?